# Access-07 Delete record when navigating away

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am building a subform in which users enter street names. The form needs to display all street names with a given fileID value in the fileID-Street table, and automatically include that ID in newly-added records.

I have this all sorted out by having the subform display a datasheet with those two columns. However, this sheet does not seem to include any way of deleting records, so removals will result in inflation of the table unless dealt with manually in the backend.

My goal is to automatically delete records with null or blank Street values when the user navigates away from that record or it is removed from the form by a filter. How might I go about achieving this?

My current attempt at a workaround is the delete query below, but it doesn't seem to actually *do* anything; fixing this would probably be my next best bet if what I'm looking for is impossible.

```
DELETE *
FROM [fileID-Street]
WHERE [fileID-Street]!Street Is Null;
```

Edit: It appears that the workaround failed because double-clicking the query causes it to run as a Select query instead of a Delete query; opening the SQL view and clicking the Run button fixed that; however, if the automated delete-on-navigating-away is possible, that would still be a far preferable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is add some VBA to your form's AfterUpdate and AfterInsert events.  So it will look something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "MyQueryName"
End Sub
```

MyQueryName will be the name of the delete query that you saved.

Comment: The first suggestion has exactly the same result as my original workaround; namely, none. Running the query simply opens a results datasheet with fileID and Street columns, and two empty records. The second idea results in a type mismatch error. While I was able to resolve this error by replacing 0 with "x", the same non-result occurs.

Comment: And if you replace "DELETE" with "SELECT *", are any records returned?

Comment: See edit to question; double-clicking the query in the project explorer was running it as a Select query.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but at this point I'm starting to think my original goal was impossible; I'll accept this one for now, potentially to be changed if a better solution arises.

Comment: As a follow-up, however, this method (though with the query triggered by Current instead of AfterUpdate) generates a warning message each time it is triggered. This can be suppressed with the method [here](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/suppress_warnings.html).